# Boot partition on Raid?

Tags: boot, raid1

I have a machine with two HD drives. I want to use Raid1 for redundancy to avoid data loss.

I have two possible scenarios:

1- Install /boot partition on both drives using Raid1.

2- Install 2 separate /boot partitions on each drive without Raid.

My concern is to be able to the system even if one HD failed. Will this requirement be met in both cases or at least in one them?

I think the performance will not be an issue here.

I am talking about a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to install grub separately in each MBR, but it can be done with `/boot` via RAID 1. You may have to switch the boot drive in the event of failure though, if the first drive fails.

Comment: If you use the proper `map` commands in grub, you can install it to the MBR such that each thinks itself the first disk. And if you have to yank the first disk and boot from the second, grub won't have any issues because the white lie you told it during `grub-install` is now the truth. Now that grub2's come around I don't know how applicable this is, but worked well enough with the original